# change android studio project package name and title?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, native-activity

My android studio project is monolithic. It uses the NDK along with a NativeActivity. I'm wanting to be able to release multiple apps via this same project. I don't want to copy it and certainly not have to create new ones and start from scratch. I simply want a way to change the package name and all relevant variables in order for android to distinguish this as a separate app even though it's the same project i'm using for all of them. It's a bit risky and dangerous, too, because in the process i risk breaking it and having to redo the whole thing. Does any know for certain what I can do?

Comment: used this link **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio**

Comment: ok thanks but im a bit worried because this is a NativeActivity. i still have a com.example.packagename underneath the java folder, it's just that the initial activity being launched is not in that folder, so im just wondering if its something to watch out for.